# cloud_firestore_platform_interface: Are we supposed to do all firestore operations from this package instead now?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, migrate

I was going to the changelog for `cloud_firestore` when I realised that one of them indicated 'migrate' to `cloud_firestore_platform_interface`. I was wondering what this means. I am especially curious as it doesn't make sense for google to leave a package buggy(? I just learnt that my app will crash if a `Transaction` was attempted while client was offline instead of throwing an `Exception` or `Error` as inidicated from this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34789#issuecomment-504134476). If I am supposed to use `Firestore` from this new package can someone recommend a guide?

New Question on Transactions:  [Firestore: Transactions crashing when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487206/firestore-transactions-crashing-when-offline)

Comment: Peter's answer correctly explains what has changed, and that this **shouldn't** have any major effect on your code. If you're having problems getting your code to run, please include the [minimum, complete code with which we can reproduce, and the error message you get](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in your question.

Comment: I will just start a new question then since this feels like 2 unrelated questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was going to the changelog for cloud_firestore when I realised that one of them indicated 'migrate' to cloud_firestore_platform_interface.

It just means that `cloud_firestore` is also using the package `cloud_firestore_platform_instance`.

From the docs:

> A common platform interface for the cloud_firestore plugin.
> This interface allows platform-specific implementations of the cloud_firestore plugin, as well as the plugin itself, to ensure they are supporting the same interface.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_platform_interface

If you want to use `cloud_firestore`, then you still need to use `cloud_firestore` plugin as usual, nothing has changed.

Comment: Do you have any idea or update regarding transactions? And if you don't mind, could you further explain the purpose of platform instance then